# c# Generics new() constraints with type: (new(T))

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I'm building a little helper to turn EF4 objects to POCOs.
(I know there is AutoMapper, but I'm having a c# dilemma at this time)

How can I make this work (the **where P: new(E)** is not legal
I wish to make sure the P (POCO) class as a constructor that takes the E class
(hence handling the transformation)

How can I make this work ?

How can I make a generic function in C# that can take a new(type) constraint ?

```
   public static List<P> ListConvert<E, P>(List<E> efList) where P: new(E)
    {
        List<P> pList = new List<P>();

        foreach (E item in efList)
        {
            P myItem = new P(item);
            pList.Add(myItem);
        }
        return pList;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such constraint. What you *can* do is have an extra parameter:

```
public static List<P> ListConvert<E, P>(List<E> efList, Func<E, P> func)
```

That way it isn't required to be a constructor, but you can pass in a delegate which *calls* the constructor:

```
ListConvert(list, x => new Foo(x))
```

I have a blue-sky idea which would enable constructor constraints, called ["static interfaces"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) - these would only be useful for generic constraints, but would also enable some operator use cases.

Comment: "static interfaces" - you should try generics in F#

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The `new` constraint only allows you to create objects via a [public parameterless constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as `P : new(E)`, but you could have the caller supply a delegate that knows how to construct a `P` given an `E`:

```
public static List<P> ListConvert<E, P>(List<E> efList, Func<E, P> converter)
{
    List<P> pList = new List<P>();

    foreach (E item in efList)
    {
        P myItem = converter(item);
        pList.Add(myItem);
    }
    return pList;
}
```

However, if you're doing this, you may as well use LINQ: `efList.Select(e => new P(e)).ToList()`.

Comment: the Where P: new(e) has the same problem... but I think it doesn't need to be there with the converter